# Wordpress register sidebar and call it on single post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, widget, sidebar

I have registered a new Sidebar called "MagazinSidebar", which I can see in the widget area.

```
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'MagazinSidebar',
'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar_widget">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h3>',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

and tried to call it if the category is 'Magazin', but it does not appear in the Magazin Category...

```
    //get template sidebar
if ( in_category( 'Magazin' )) {
if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('MagazinSidebar') ) ;
    }
else {
 get_sidebar();
}
```

Any ideas? :) Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling that code?

Answer (score 1):

use `get_sidebar()` function with your registered sidebarname.
Here in your case use `get_sidebar('MagazinSidebar')`.

```
if ( in_category( 'Magazin' )) {
get_sidebar('MagazinSidebar');
    }
else {
 get_sidebar();
}
```